# Пытаюсь соединиться в Google Drive

Tags: c#, .net

Создал Google Drive
открыл папку для общего пользования.
Создал ключ клиента вот [тут](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/) 
подгрузил нужные [библиотеки](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/)

использую .NET FrameWork 4.6

```
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Services;

public static void TEST()
{
DriveService services = null;
            try
            {
                services = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApiKey = "Мой ключ API",  // from https://console.developers.google.com (Public API access)
                    ApplicationName = "Имя проекта",
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Display.MsgBox(ex.Message); }
}
```

Выбрасывает исключение

> The type initializer or 'Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsjftJsonSerializer'
>   threw an exception

Что не так делаю?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892859/the-type-initializer-for-google-apis-json-newtonsoftjsonserializer-threw-an-ex